# Memory Error when using float32 in dask array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask, numpy-memmap

I am trying to import a 1.25 GB dataset into python using **`dask.array`**

The file is a 1312*2500*196 Array of **`uint16`**'s. I need to convert this to a **`float32`** array for later processing.

I have managed to stitch together this Dask array in `uint16`, however when I try to convert to `float32` I get a **memory error**.

It doesn't matter what I do to the chunk size, I will always get a memory error.

I create the array by concatenating the array in lines of 100 (breaking the 2500 dimension up into little pieces of 100 lines, since `dask` can't natively read `.RAW` imaging files I have to use **`numpy.memmap()`** to read the file and then create the array.
Below I will supply a "as short as possible" code snippet:

I have tried two methods:

1) Create the full `uint16` array and then try to convert to `float32`:

(note: the `memmap` is a 1312x100x196 array and lines ranges from 0 to 24)

```
for i in range(lines):
    NewArray = da.concatenate([OldArray,Memmap],axis=0)
    OldArray = NewArray
return NewArray
```

and then I use

```
Float32Array = FinalArray.map_blocks(lambda FinalArray: FinalArray * 1.,dtype=np.float32)
```

In method 2:

```
for i in range(lines):
    NewArray = da.concatenate([OldArray,np.float32(Memmap)],axis=0)
    OldArray = NewArray
return NewArray
```

Both methods result in a memory error.

**Is there any reason for this?**

I read that `dask` array is capable of doing up to 100 GB dataset calculations.

I tried all chunk sizes (from as small as 10x10x10 to a single line)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dask.array from a numpy memmap array directly with the `da.from_array` function

```
x = load_memmap_numpy_array_from_raw_file(filename)
d = da.from_array(x, chunks=...)
```

You can change the dtype with the `astype` method

```
d = d.astype(np.float32)
```